# Gradle fails on assembleDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mockito, android-espresso

I'm trying to add mockito as dependency for my android project, but I'm getting the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/hamcrest/Description;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Apparently, `hamcrest` is a transitive dependency for multiple dependencies.

1. In a project with hundreds dependencies, how can one determine which ones have overlapping transitive dependencies?
2. What is the best way to solve such a problem?

My test dependencies are the following:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: I think for Android you need to use [dexmaker](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker) in order to use Mockito. Can you please replace your mockito dependency with 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2' and see if the error goes away?

Comment: @LawrenceChoy thank you for you suggestion. This works great! Although I would like to know, is there generic way to solve such problems (i.e. to determine and then to exclude transitive dependencies)? If i add `androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'` I have the same problem again and I need powermock for my tests.

Comment: You can run `gradle dependencies --configuration androidTestCompile` to see what versions of hamcrest are being brought in. I'm guess you would see different versions of `hamcrest-core`/`hamcrest-integration`/`hamcrest-library`, causes conflicts as some classes were moved around between those modules.